# Levels - need exact format

Tags: object, format, levels

How do I get such a format?

> example
>
> [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2
>   Levels: 1 2

where:

> mode(example)
>
> [1] "numeric"
>
> levels(example)
>
> [1] "1" "2"
>
> mode(levels(example))
>
> [1] "character"

I try to create a numeric object and attribute the values and the levels as.character, but i get something different and i need exactly this format… Still learning R basics...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to obtain the desired result as follows:

```
> class3<-as.numeric(c("1","2","3"))
> class3.f<-factor(class3)
> class3.f

[1] 1 2 3 
Levels: 1 2 3
```

If you have any better advice feel free to post… Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
example <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)                 
levels(as.factor(example))

[1] "1" "2"
```